# Scroll long text inside WKInterfaceLabel?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacelabel

Simple question: is there a way to make a `WKInterfaceLabel` scroll if its text is too long to fit within the label’s frame? Something akin to a `UITextView`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can definitely do this. All you need to do is set the following properties on the `WKInterfaceLabel` in the Storyboard.

- **Label => Lines** = 0 (WatchKit will set the right number)
- **Size => Width** = "Relative to Container"
- **Size => Height** = "Size to Fit Content"

This will let you scroll to your heart's content. I just mocked it up in a sample app and it works exactly as you would expect.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That’s ALMOST perfect, but what I’m trying to do alongside this is keep the text vertically centred in the watch’s screen. Given the watch’s status bar, I was apply an adjustment to the height of the label to compensate (i.e. cutting 8pt off on the bottom edge to match those on the top that make up the status bar). I wonder if I can maintain that using the Size to Fit option.

Comment: You won't be able to produce that effect because you would be hardcoding the height and it would end up truncating instead of growing.

Comment: This is not working for me. My goal is to scroll the content text of the label inside that label area. And it simply does "Size to Fit" which is not requirement.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't possible to have a `WKInterfaceLabel` scroll its contents. Your only choice is to truncate the text or allow the label to grow and accommodate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set label's property set height of label as text size

as below

```
Set Lines Property = 0 (WatchKit auto set the right number)

Set Width = "Relative to Container" & Height = "Size to Fit Content"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these steps respectively to Achieve result like this image.This is a ***Scrollable View***.

[image]

I use two groups

**Group1:**
*Group1 include image,heading Label,date Label and Group2*

> Group1 layout is vertical
>
> Width:Relative to Container
>
> Height:Size to Fit Content

***Image:***

> image width:relative to container(0.8)
>
> image height:Fixed(60)

***Heading and Date Label:***

> Width:Relative to Container
>
> Height:Size to Fit Content

**Group2:**
*Group2 includes description Label*

> Group2 layout is vertical
>
> Width:Relative to Container
>
> Height:Size to Fit Content

Description Label:

> Width:Relative to Container
>
> Height:Size to Fit Content