# WKInterfaceLabel won't scroll when it is inside a group

Tags: swift, interface-builder, watchkit, wkinterfacelabel

Whenever I set my WKInterfaceLabel lines to 0 with the height "size to fit content" I am able to scroll through text whenever there is a lot.

However, if I put the same label inside a group, I can longer scroll through the label text. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Could it be because your group's height isn't also set to "size to fit content?"

Comment: Here is your solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/35316639/1591336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Group to fit content. Your Group is hiding you label display.